# RecyclerView items in a ConstraintLayout overlaps after ChangeBounds transition animation

Tags: java, android

I am trying to animate a calendar and a list below it by swipe animations by using ConstraintLayout transition animations. It works but sometimes RecyclerView items glitches and overlaps. What is the cause and how to solve it?

Demonstration: https://gfycat.com/FlowerySelfreliantFennecfox

I used following libraries:

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3'
implementation 'com.github.pwittchen:swipe-rx2:0.3.0'
```

Java code:

```
private void SetGestures(){
        swipe = new Swipe();
        swipe.setListener(new SwipeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSwipingLeft(MotionEvent event) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSwipedLeft(MotionEvent event) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwipingRight(MotionEvent event) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSwipedRight(MotionEvent event) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwipingUp(MotionEvent event) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSwipedUp(MotionEvent event) {

                CollapseCalendar();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwipingDown(MotionEvent event) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSwipedDown(MotionEvent event) {
                ExpandCalendar();
                return true;
            }
        });
        calendarView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return swipe.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
    }

    private void SetRecyclerGestures(){
        rvCalendarFragment.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if (!calendarCollapsed && newState == SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING){
                    CollapseCalendar();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void ExpandCalendar(){
        calendarView.state().edit().setCalendarDisplayMode(CalendarMode.MONTHS).commit();

        calendarCollapsed = false;

        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.clone(getActivity(),R.layout.fragment_calendar_new);

        ChangeBounds transition = new ChangeBounds();
        transition.setInterpolator(new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator(0.5f));
        transition.setDuration(300);
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(consFragmentCalendar,transition);
        constraintSet.applyTo(consFragmentCalendar);
    }

    private void CollapseCalendar(){
        calendarView.state().edit().setCalendarDisplayMode(CalendarMode.WEEKS).commit();
        calendarCollapsed = true;

        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.clone(getActivity(),R.layout.fragment_calendar_new_collapsed);

        ChangeBounds transition = new ChangeBounds();
        transition.setInterpolator(new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator(0.5f));
        transition.setDuration(300);
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(consFragmentCalendar,transition);
        constraintSet.applyTo(consFragmentCalendar);

    }
```

fragment_calendar_new.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/consFragmentCalendar">

    <com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
        android:background="@color/grey_500"
        android:id="@+id/calendarViewFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvCalendarFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_calendar_new_collapsed.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/consFragmentCalendar">

    <com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarViewFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvCalendarFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Adapter code:

```
public class NewCalendarEventsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewCalendarEventsAdapter.NewCalendarViewHolder>{

    private ArrayList<CalendarEvent> events;

    public NewCalendarEventsAdapter(ArrayList<CalendarEvent> events) {
        this.events = events;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NewCalendarViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_calendar_new, parent, false);
        return new NewCalendarViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NewCalendarViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CalendarEvent event = events.get(position);
        holder.tvCalendarEventDate.setText(event.getStartDate());
        holder.tvCalendarEventDate.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(event.getBackgroundColor()));
        holder.tvCalendarEventTitle.setText(event.getTitle());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return events.size();
    }

    public static class NewCalendarViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        TextView tvCalendarEventDate, tvCalendarEventTitle;

        public NewCalendarViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvCalendarEventDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCalendarEventDate);
            tvCalendarEventTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCalendarEventTitle);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO:
        }
    }
}
```

list_item_calendar_new.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCalendarEventDate"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@color/blue_400"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCalendarEventTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvCalendarEventDate"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your code for recyclerView items ?

Comment: Added adapter code

Comment: also add your item xml please

Comment: added adapter item xml

Comment: your code is alright. The problem seems to be with your animation. Did you tried increasing expand collapse time of calender, or removing the animation ?

Comment: Changing animation duration did not fix the problem. Removing animation did. However I would like to keep the animation.